# Drupal 6 - Email Newsletter Module - Attaching nodes/stories content, mail collect send to access denied page

Tags: drupal, drupal-nodes

I have hard time using this module in my Drupal 6 site. Since I downloaded and installed required modules such as:

**Email Newsletter**,

Bounced Email,

Deliver,

HTML to Text,

Identity Hash,

Publication,

Schedule,

Subscribe Members,

Subscribed,

Subscribed Silverlight,

Templates,

I have problem solving some issues, enewsletter sends mails with proper information in Tokens, but it does not attach any nodes nor story information. I've insured that publishing options in content type are selected (**default checked**) and followed instruction described in readme.txt, but nothing happen. 
I receive test emails only with token information nothing more. There is **something else**, when i set block with collect mails option block show up as predicted, but when i enter particular e-mail address after submitting, page reloads to access denied page.

I'm more designer than developer, so I could use some help.

Cheers

Comment: Use this module http://drupal.org/project/simplenews_content_selection to select the particular content, You can select any number of contents. Hope it helps you!!!

Comment: Well it worked, I wonder is there some option to send newest content automatically and cyclically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this module [drupal.org/project/simplenews_content_selection](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews_content_selection) to select the particular content, You can select any number of contents

To send automatically use the below module

http://drupal.org/project/simplenews_scheduler Download and install the module, choose the appropriate setting, see the  below image

[image]